# No value given for one or more required parameters. showing error

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net

```
 <asp:AccessDataSource ID="productsubtype" Runat="server" DataFile="~/access_db/db_tables.mdb" 

            SelectCommand="SELECT [type], [id],[subtype] FROM [prod_subtype]"


               UpdateCommand="UPDATE [prod_subtype] SET [subtype]=@subtype WHERE [id]=@id"
                DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [prod_subtype] WHERE [id]=@id" 
                FilterExpression="type='{0}'">


                <UpdateParameters>

                    <asp:Parameter Name="subtype" Type="string" />
                </UpdateParameters>
                <DeleteParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="id" Type="string" />
                </DeleteParameters>
                 <FilterParameters>
                <asp:ControlParameter Name="type" DefaultValue="-1" 
                   Type="String" ControlID="gdproducttype"
                    PropertyName="SelectedValue"></asp:ControlParameter>
            </FilterParameters>
        </asp:AccessDataSource>
```

When i press delete button in gridview i am getting error

Comment: @ gbn No value given for one or more required parameters

Comment: What is the default selected id in the grid view ?

Comment: @ Aristos this is the id of grid view ID="productsubtypes"

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your UpdateParameters to the following:

```
<UpdateParameters>
    <asp:Parameter Name="id" Type="string" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="subtype" Type="string" />
</UpdateParameters>
```